# Meteor template updating

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am new to Meteor. I built simple test up and got stuck on very easy part. Content of my webpage updates only when db changes, but how can I force it update when function returning results changes? Here is part of code of my application:

client.js:

```
Meteor.subscribe("tasks");

var search_query = "";

Template.page.tasks = function() {
    return Tasks.find({title: {$regex: search_query}});
};

Template.task.events({
    'click .checkmark': function() {
        Tasks.update({_id: this._id}, {$set: {done: !this.done}});
    }
});

Template.page.events({
    'keyup .search': function() {
        search_query = $(".search").val();
    }
});
```

todo.html:

```
<head>
  <title>Todo list</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  {{> page}}
</body>

<template name="page">
    <div class="tasks">
        <h1>Collections TODOs</h1>
        <input type="text" class="search" placeholder="Search...">
        {{#each tasks}}
            {{> task}}
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</template>

<template name="task">
    <div class="task well well-small">
        <button type="button" class="close cancel">&times;</button>
        <h3>
            {{#if done}}
                <button type="button" class="checkmark done">&#10003;</button>
            {{else}}


    <button type="button" class="checkmark muted">&#10003;</button>
        {{/if}}
        {{title}}
    </h3>
    <div class="creator muted">{{creator}}</div>
    <p>{{description}}</p>
</div>
```

So now, I expect whenever user types something in input.search box variable `search_query` is changed and now `Template.page.tasks` returns different results. But nothing really updates. You can look at app on http://slava.meteor.com

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a [reactive variable](http://docs.meteor.com/#reactivity) to dynamically run the search again. Make `search_query` a `Session` variable like this

```
Template.page.tasks = function() {
    return Tasks.find({title: {$regex: Session.get("search_query") }});
};
```

And in your event:

```
Template.page.events({
   'keyup .search': function() {
        Session.set("search_query", $(".search").val());
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But now, every time template update text from my search field dissappers. So looks like page gets refreshed. Can you give any hints, how can I build better UI?

Comment: I obviously can set `<input type="text" class="search" placeholder="Search..." value={{search_query}}>` and manually put focus on it, but it is still kinda odd

Comment: See [preseve-input](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_preserve) for a means of preserving user input when the page is refreshed.